# Ruby Sinatra App in Windows Linux Bash not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the Linux Bash in Windows 10 preview, then I installed Ruby and Sinatra, no problems, then I created a simple Sinatra application for testing purposes like this one:

```
require 'sinatra'

configure do
    set :bind, "0.0.0.0"
    set :port, "6025"
end

get '/' do
    "Hello"
end
```

I run the application w/o errors then I open the browser and type the address of the app but it does nothing, it keeps loading w/o result, the same with cURL, it never gets the result, it just hangs, I tried dissabling the firewall and running the process as admin or root, no success, what can i do to get this to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by running the app with Puma instead of using Thin. So it's probably a Thin problem (didn't have much time to identify why)

`ruby test.rb -s Puma`